# How to create picker as shown in attached picture in xamarin.forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

How to create a picker as shown in attached picture I am using xamarin.forms

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use custom renderer to remove the line around the picker.

This article might get you started [Here](https://xamgirl.com/picker-with-right-side-icon-in-xamarin-forms/)

After that, use `<frame>` with custom background image and inside it add a stack layout where you will add the label in the first line and the custom picker.